# Doctrine 2.1 - Call to undefined method + MyMethod(Proxy)?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have two classes:

**News**:

```
/** @Entity @Table(name="news") */
class News {
    /**
     * @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(type="integer")
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @Column(type="text")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $content;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="news")
     * @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
     */ 
    protected $author;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="NewsCategory", inversedBy="news")
     * @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
     */ 
    protected $category;

    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $add_date;

    # CATEGORY methods
    public function setCategory($val) { if($val instanceof NewsCategory) $this->category = $val; }
    public function getCategory() { return $this->category; }
}
```

**NewsCategory**:

```
/** @Entity @Table(name="news_category") */
class NewsCategory {
    /**
     * @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(type="integer")
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50, unique=TRUE)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="News", mappedBy="category")
     */
    protected $news;    

    public function __construct() {
        $this->news = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    }

    public function setName($name) { $this->name = $name; }
    public function getName() { return $this->name; }

    public function getNews() { return $this->news; }
}
```

I want to download one news with this query:

```
$q = $this->db->createQuery("SELECT n FROM News n WHERE n.id = :id");
$q->setParameter('id', $_GET['id']);
$news = $q->getResult();
```

And next, I want to get id of a Category related to this news with

```
$news->getCategory()->getId()
```

With code above, I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DoctrineProxies\NewsCategoryProxy::getId() in C:\[...]\newsController.php on line 61
```

What's wrong? Why my `NewsCategory` class can't see `getId()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good practice to allways declare your class' members private and to generate getters and setters on your class members.

In your case, you don't generate getters and setters (there is no `getId()` method on your `NewCategory` class).

That's how your `NewCategory` class should look like :

```
/** @Entity @Table(name="news_category") */
class NewsCategory {
    /**
     * @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(type="integer")
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50, unique=TRUE)
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="News", mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $news;    

    public function __construct() {
        $this->news = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    }

    public function getId(){ return $this->id;}
    public function setId($id){ $this->id = $id;}

    public function setName($name) { $this->name = $name; }
    public function getName() { return $this->name; }

    public function setNews($news) {$this->news = $news;}
    public function getNews() { return $this->news; }

}
```

The generated proxies will not generate *magically* getters and setters on every of your properties (it would break the OOP's encapsulation principle).
You can find more documentations about proxies here : http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/configuration.html#proxy-objects

Comment: On doctrine documentation, they have members on `protected`. And still, `protected` type is in Your example :). So what's better than?

Comment: You're right, I corrected my answer and mark the members as private. As you can see in the doctrine documentation's link I gave they don't access properties outside the class. [Here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/working-with-objects.html#entity-object-graph-traversal) you can see they use public getters and setters on private properties.

Comment: Don't just blindly use `private` or `protected` without knowing why. `private` restricts access to those properties to the owning class only (no sub-classes). `protected` grants access to child classes. One benefit to using `protected` is that it allows your [entities to be serialised](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.2/en/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities)